# button not working in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I cannot figure out why my `handleDelete` function isn't running. When I click 'Delete' nothing at all happens.

In dev tools I see the value for the delete button is correct but `onClick` with it's attributes doesn't show up at all.

```
var MainContainer = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
      return {
        name: 'JK_MNO',
        friends: [], //friends is items
        text: ''
      }
    },
    handleChange: function(e){
      //like the onChange function
        this.setState({
            text: e.target.value
        });
    },
    handleSubmit: function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      if(this.state.text !== '') {
        var nextfriend = this.state.friends.concat([{
          text: this.state.text, id: Date.now()
        }]);
        var nextText = '';
        this.setState({
          friends: nextfriend, text: nextText
        });

      }
    },
    handleDelete: function(e){
      console.log(this.state.friends);
      this.friends.splice (this.props.friend.id);
      this.setState({
        friends: friends
      });
    },
    render: function(){
      return (
        <div>
          <h3> Name: {this.state.name} </h3>
          <ShowList friends={this.state.friends} />
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
              Enter Friends: <input className="friendInput" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.text} />
            </form> 
        </div>
      );
    }
});

var ShowList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var createFriend = function(friend) {
      return (
        <li key={friend.id}>{friend.text} <button onClick={this.props.handleDelete} value={friend.id}>Delete</button> </li>
      );
    };
    return <ul>{this.props.friends.map(createFriend.bind(this))}</ul>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<MainContainer />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/USERALPHA32/bdc9trux/

Comment: Always include relevant code directly in your question.

Comment: FWIW, the first step to debug this on your own would have been to check the value of `this.props.handleDelete` inside `StepList`. You would have seen that it is `undefined`. Of course if there is no function, nothing can be called on click! Then you should have checked how the prop is passed to `StepList` where you would have seen that it's not passed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very close! You just need to pass your delete function down to `ShowList` as a prop:

Current:

```
<ShowList friends={this.state.friends} />
```

Suggested:

```
<ShowList friends={this.state.friends} handleDelete={this.handleDelete} />
```